# Increase Form Size programmatically in C#

Tags: c#

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 243; i >= 850; i++)
        {
            this.Width = i;

        }            
    }
```

I tried this and it isn't working. Anyone know why?

Comment: And not working means?

Comment: Change your `>=` to `<=`

Comment: Condition `i >= 850;` is always false in this case, are you using loop for animated effect?  that won't work ,loop blocks `UI` rendering. Remove the loop and just set some value.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with your code:

1. `i >= 850` is false. the Start value (243) is not greater then or equal 850, so the loop will never run. do `i <= 850` instead.
2. The loop is unnecessary. The form will not re-render for every iteration of the loop, it will just render once, when the loop is completed, with `this.Width = 850;` from the last iteration of the loop, so your whole loop can be substituted as it currently is with `this.Width = 850;`